# RedBlackTree delete using insert-method (StackOverFlowError)

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I somehow get a StackOverFlowError when testing my following method. The tests and helper functions are 100% correct. I'm trying to implement a delete-method for a BinarySearchTree using the insert-method I already implemented (and works).

Here is my code:

```
    public void delete(TreeNode toDelete) {  
    TreeNode _rootTmp = _root;
    RedBlackTree tree = new RedBlackTree();
    if(_root == null) {
        tree.insert(_root);
    }

    if(_rootTmp.left != _nil) { 
        if(!_rootTmp.left.equals(toDelete)) {
            tree.insert(_rootTmp.left); 
        }
        delete(_rootTmp.left); 
    }
    if(_rootTmp.right != _nil) { 
        if(!_rootTmp.right.equals(toDelete)) {
            tree.insert(_rootTmp.right);
        }
        delete(_rootTmp.right);
    }
    if(_rootTmp.left == _nil && _rootTmp.right == _nil) {
        _root = tree._root;   
    }
}
```

At our RedBlackTree Class we use _nil instead of null for checking if there is another node or not.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Since `_rootTmp` never changes and `_rootTmp.left` never changes, why do you believe that recursive call `delete(_rootTmp.left)` would ever end?

Comment: This seems like a very strange way to perform a delete, what benefit is it supposed to provide over swapping with the next or previous in-order node if necessary and yanking the node from the tree?

Comment: But _rootTmp changes because its a recursive method or not? When I do "delete(_rootTmp.left)" my new node starting the recursion is _rootTmp.left or not?